# Rotation of image with Raphael 2 does not work

Tags: javascript, animation, raphael

when I try to animate the rotation of an image (with Raphael 2), which I have done before successfully with Raphael 1, nothing happens.
Animating another property such as height does work.

```
this.image.animate({rotation: this.angle + " " + this.centerY + " " + this.centerY}, this.animationTime, '<>');
```

Do you have an idea?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As I see on  http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html element.animate does not have an rotation parameter(at least in version 2.0; maybe in earlier version it was there?).

You have to use

```
this.image.animate({transform:"r"+this.angle + "," + this.centerY + "," + this.centerY}, this.animationTime);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this.image.rotate(45);
```

I have noticed that the old way has been updated in 2.0.